# xquery sort out by id

Tags: loops, xquery

i would like to know how could i sortout the unwanted element with loop that it would not return elements with the same id 
Fiddle has a example and expected : https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyG

```
let $act :=(
<act id="1">
 <data>hel1lo</data>
 <data>hel1lo</data>
</act>,
<act id="2">
 <data>hel1lo</data>
 <data>hel1lo</data>
</act>,
<act id="3">
 <data>hel1lo</data>
 <data>hel1lo</data>
</act>
)
let $act1 :=(
<act id="4">
 <data>hel1lo</data>
 <data>hel1lo</data>
</act>,
<act id="1">
 <data>hel1lo</data>
 <data>hel1lo</data>
</act>
)

for $data in ($act,$act1)
where $act/@id != $act1/@id 
return
$data
```

i would like to know how could i sort out from $act1 element `<act id="1">`

exptected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<act id="1">
   <data>hel1lo</data>
   <data>hel1lo</data>
</act>
<act id="2">
   <data>hel1lo</data>
   <data>hel1lo</data>
</act>
<act id="3">
   <data>hel1lo</data>
   <data>hel1lo</data>
</act>
<act id="4">
   <data>hel1lo</data>
   <data>hel1lo</data>
</act>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a problem that can be solved by grouping by `@id` and then returning the first item of each group:

```
for $data in ($act,$act1)
where $act/@id != $act1/@id
group by $id := $data/@id
return
$data[1]
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyG/1